# Checking QValidator's state

Tags: python, pyqt

First, sorry for my bad English.

I'm trying to get an IP from user. I'm using QRegExpValidator for checking user input. The validator blocks unwanted characters succesfully. But I want to learn it's a proper IP when user clicked the button. Of course I can check the text manually, but there seems a better way, using QValidator's state enum. QValidator.Acceptable is what I need to check. But I can't figure out how I can use it

Here is what I need to use:
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qvalidator.html#State-enum

And here is what I tried(abstracted from main program):

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from functools import partial

class Gui(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)

        editLayout=QtGui.QFormLayout()

        edit=QtGui.QLineEdit()
        edit.setMinimumWidth(125)
        regex=QtCore.QRegExp("\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}")
        validator=QtGui.QRegExpValidator(regex, edit)

        edit.setValidator(validator)

        editLayout.addRow("Enter Client IP:", edit)

        button=QtGui.QPushButton("Add Client")
        button.clicked.connect(partial(self.addClientButtonClicked, edit, validator))

        layout=QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(editLayout)
        layout.addWidget(button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def addClientButtonClicked(self, edit, validator):
        print("ip=", edit.text())
        print(validator.State==QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate)


app=QtGui.QApplication([])
g=Gui()
g.show()
app.exec_()
```

Desired output:

```
ip= 192.168.
False
ip= 192.168.2.1
True
```

But thats what I get:

```
ip= 192.168.
False
ip= 192.168.2.1
False
```

What is the proper way of checking QValidator's state?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing the right thing here. The comparison:

```
validator.State==QtGui.QValidator.Intermediate
```

Compares an enumeration *type* to one of its values - this will *always* be `False`!

Use the `validate` method instead:

```
def addClientButtonClicked(self, edit, validator):
    print("ip=", edit.text())
    print(validator.validate(edit.text(), 0))
```

Then the result for `192.168.2.1` is:

```
('ip=', PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'192.168.2.1'))
(2, 0)
```

The first element of the tuple returned by `validate` is the state, which you can compare to the various states of `QValidator`:

```
def addClientButtonClicked(self, edit, validator):
    state, pos = validator.validate(edit.text(), 0)
    print(state == QtGui.QValidator.Acceptable)
```

Prints `True` for `192.168.2.1`

Comment: thanks :). it worked perfectly :). i have a (maybe stupid) question, why the state objects has functions like "real","imag","conjugate", are they derived from complex numbers, why? :)

Comment: @utdmr: interesting (though unrelated) - I really don't know, maybe it's some artifact of PyQt's implementation