# How to restrict user input in QLineEdit in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt4, qlineedit

I have a `QLineEdit` and i want to restrict `QLineEdit` to accept only integers. It should work like inputmask. But I dont want to use `inputmask`, because if user clicks on `QLineEdit` cursor will be at the position where mouse was clicked. and user need to navigate to 0 position and type what eve he wants.

Is there any alternate for this.

Answer (score 55):

you can use QValidator. It works like:

```
# from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator
# from PyQt6.QtGui import QIntValidator

# allow only integers
onlyInt = QIntValidator()
onlyInt.setRange(0, 4)
lineEdit.setValidator(onlyInt)
```

Comment: This is the appropriate way to do it. Using validator.

Comment: how would I use this in combination with a qlineedit() ?

Comment: @Ben lineEdit is a QLineEdit() widget, so before that line assume this:

lineEdit = QLineEdit()
...

Answer (score 9):

you can use exception handling for validating this:

```
number = self.ui.number_lineEdit.text()
try:
    number = int(number)
except Exception:
    QtGui.QMessageBox.about(self, 'Error','Input can only be a number')
    pass
```

you can also use [validators](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qvalidator.html) to validate input strings.

Comment: i heard about `validators`, but did not get find a correct example on how to set it to `QLineEdit`. Mean while i will try your approch. I think Validators are the good options for professional approach.

Comment: try learning from this question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770441/checking-qvalidators-state

Comment: A good exemple of how to use validators is here: http://snorf.net/blog/2014/08/09/using-qvalidator-in-pyqt4-to-validate-user-input/

Comment: @maurobio - linkupdate: https://snorfalorpagus.net/blog/2014/08/09/validating-user-input-in-pyqt4-using-qvalidator