# PyQt: QLineEdit input mask for only Integer or only String and length restriction

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

These are the 2 questions(both can be solved by InputMask?)

1. I want to restrict the user input to 16 characters only
2. In a field like 'Age/ID', I would like the user's input to be integer only, if the user enters a string it must not be accepted or the user must not be able to type in a string in the first place.

I'm not sure how I can implement the first part in real-time,i.e., the user types a max of 16, nothing beyond 16 appears.

This is my code(not working) for the 2nd part of the question:

```
self.onlyInt = QIntValidator()
self.lineEdit_15.setValidator(self.onlyInt)
det15=str(self.lineEdit_15.text())
list_val.append(det15)
```

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qlineedit.html#setMaxLength This can be used to implement the first part in "real time"

Comment: As for the second part, refer to this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829782/how-to-restrict-user-input-in-qlineedit-in-pyqt

Comment: I would highly recommend using a QSpinBox for the integer input field.

Answer (score 2):

To solve the first question we only have to establish a maximum size:

```
self.lineedit_15.setMaxLength(16)
```

In contrast the second QIntValidator question only works up to a maximum equal to `2147483647` since it is the maximum integer: 2**31-1, The solution is to use regular expressions:

```
rx = QRegExp("\d+")
self.lineedit_15.setValidator(QRegExpValidator(rx))
```